# How can I handle image upload using multer in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom, multer

I keep getting req.files as undefined while uploading an image using the react-router-dom  Form element.
**this is my controller.**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const Product = require("../Models/Product");
const APIFeatures = require("../utils/ApiFeatures");
const catchAsync = require("../utils/CatchAsync");

const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
});

exports.uploadProductImage = (req, res, next) => {
  upload.single("image");
  next();
};

exports.createProduct = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  const productData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    category: req.body.category,
    subCategory: req.body.subCategory,
    tags: req.body.tags,
    productImage: req.file.filename,
  };
  console.log(productData);

  const newDoc = await Product.create(productData);
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        newDoc,
      },
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

This is my react component

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { Form, redirect, useLoaderData, useNavigation } from "react-router-dom"
import "./AddProducts.scss"

import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const AddProducts = () => {
    return (
        <div className='add-products'>
            <Form method="POST" className="form-control" id="add-products-form" encType="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onChange={e => e.target.files[0]} />
                <button className="add-btn"</button>
                <ToastContainer />
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddProducts

export const action = async ({ request }) => {

    const method = request.method;
    const data = await request.formData();
    const tags = data.get("tags");
    const tagArray = tags.split(",").map(tag => tag.trim());

    const subCategoryValue = data.get('subCategory')
    let subCategory;
    if (subCategoryValue !== "noSubCategory") {
        subCategory = subCategoryValue
    }

    const productData = {
        name: data.get("name"),
        description: data.get("description"),
        category: data.get("category"),
        image: data.get("image"),
        subCategory: subCategory,
        tags: tagArray,
    }

    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/products/create-products"
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(productData)
    })
    console.log(productData)

    if (!response.ok) {
        toast.error("Failed, Something bad happened try again")
    } else {
        toast.success("Product added Successfully")
    }

    return redirect("/admin");
}
```

this is my file upload when I log it out
image: File{
lastModified:1693396233345,
lastModifiedDate: Wed Aug 30 2023 14:50:33 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time){}
name: "equipments.jpg",
size: 854169,
type: "image/jpeg",
webkitRelativePath:""
can anyone help ive been stuck on this for a couple of days now

Comment: `upload.single("image");` returns a request handler, you may pass `req,res,next` to it.
`upload.single("image")(req,res,next);`

Comment: would appreciate it if you would elaborate thanks

Comment: figured it out....for anyone with the same problem I removed the header and appended all the input values to the formData instance then removed the JSON.stringify  and everything worked